# list available web services on tomcat using spring-ws

Tags: web-services, spring, tomcat, spring-ws

Is it possible to get a list of all available web services on a tomcat server?

Answer (score 1):

While it looks like this question is probably dead, I'm answering for others future reference. In short, no there is no way to get all of the services available on a server with Spring WS by itself. Spring provides a way for each server to declare its functions via a WSDL. What you need is a UDDI. Spring does not provide that functionality.

A UDDI basically documents all of the web services that have registered with it. Here the Wikipedia entry for it, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration.

If you got a UDDI installed and registered every service with it, then you'd have a full catalog.